# Automatic create SQL database and table relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For SQL Server 2008, what is the best way to automatically "draw up" the Database relation ship and table relationship too?

Is there any way to visualize database with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use database diagrams, drag and drop your tables and use the designer to create the relationships for you. Open SSMS, expand the server, expand Databases, expand the database you want and it should be the first folder. If it asks to install things, say yes and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Visio if you have it to reverse engineer the database schema. Obviously you need the additional software but it's more flexible than the Database Diagram functionality in SSMS.